# How can rearrange character of UILabel by drag and drop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just want an idea to make something like this.Suppose there is an `UILabel` `string` @"don't late." but when it will display it will show like this @"don' tlate.", Now user will rearrange those characters by dragging and dropping and make it correct word.

Now anyone can give me any idea or sample of example that how can i do that in iPhone application development?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would look into spite kit.

Comment: isn't it possible using UIKit Framework?

Comment: Yeah. It is. I would make each character it's own UILabel, have them in a view that doesn't use autolayout for in contents. Then make interactions enabled on the container view and add a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the container view. When the Gesture is performed I would do a hitTest to determine which UILabel should be panned make sure it's the foremost subview. Then update it's center property to the location of the pan gesture while the panning is happening.

Comment: The reason it suggested sprite kit is because it feels like your creating a gaming experience and it's typical easier to do that in SpriteKit.

Comment: If you can give me an example then it will great help for me.I have understood your point but i can not get the point of moving center position of the UILabel.An example please.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a sample project on [my github account](https://github.com/tobiasoleary/samples/tree/master/PanningView).

I think [raywenderlich's gesture tutorial may help you.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)

Below is the most relevant code

```
// MARK: Actions

extension ViewController {

    @IBAction func moveLabel(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer)  {

        if let labelBeingMoved = labelBeingMoved {
            labelBeingMoved.center = gesture.locationInView(labelContainer)
        }
    }

}


// MARK: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

extension ViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {


    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        let location = gesture.locationInView(labelContainer)



        //You'll have to change this to account for labels on top of one another
        for label in labels {
            if label.frame.contains(location) {
                labelBeingMoved = label
                labelContainer.bringSubviewToFront(labelBeingMoved!)
                return true
            }

        }
        return false
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help.I have done this but i want something like that suppose a string @"Wake up.",where space between "w" and "a" is fixed but i have to display like that where "a" is almost overlapping the "w" so user will move it from left to right but user should not be able like to move the character "a" which is overlapping "k".Is that make any sense?

Comment: I'm glad this starter code helped you. I don't really understand what you want, but if you want to determine if two frame are overlapping you can use the `CGRectIntersectsRect` function from [Apple's Geometry code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html).